# What is the difference between natural numbers and positive integers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, integers

I was reading sets and came to some reserved letters for a few sets.
Two of them really confused me. They were -

$\mathbb N$ :  For the set of natural numbers.

$\mathbb Z^+$ : For the set if all positive integers.

In my sense, both the sets contain $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$
Then, why are they considered different?

I searched a little on this topic and got [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180324135752/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55753.html), but it doesn't tell anything about significance of two **different** sets.

Comment: Often **N** is defined as $\{0,1,2,3,..\}$; then the sets are different. Look up the definition of it in the book/article you are reading.

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z-Plus.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/N.html

Comment: @Karl  Natural numbers don't contain 0.

Comment: @Hritik Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number ,before you make such apodictic statements.

Comment: @Karl WTH ! Wiki page says: "There is no universal agreement
about whether to include zero in
the set of natural numbers. Some
authors begin the natural
numbers with 0 , corresponding to
the non-negative integers 0, 1, 2,
3, ..., whereas others start with 1,
corresponding to the positive
integers 1, 2 , 3, ..." I'm seriously disappointed with my elementary school.

Comment: In order to not be ambiguous about definitions its better you define them properly@Hritik

Comment: If some authors do begin we 0 or do not then they should mention it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be aware that some authors define $\mathbb{N}$ to include zero.  This isn't of much consequence in itself since the properties of the set are preserved: there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ with zero and $\mathbb{N}$ without zero, both are well-ordered, and so forth—effectively, we've done nothing but "relabel" the elements.

Only when we start adding structure to these elements does the distinction become important.  For instance, if we define an addition $+: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, we might make $0$ an additive identity.  Therefore, when one writes "$\mathbb{N}$" in such a scenario (most scenarios), then it should be made clear which definition is intended.

Now, if we take both to mean the set $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$, then whether one writes $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is immaterial.  However, using $\mathbb{Z}^+$ removes ambiguity since $\mathbb{Z}^+$ definitively does not include zero, and we would not have to go out of our way defining $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What if you are questioned: Write the elements of set N?  Will you include zero? Why is this ambiguity?

Comment: @Hritik the ambiguity is due to history, some places had $0$ included and others didn't. If I was asked to write the natural numbers, I'd ask them for which definition I should use.

Comment: Alternatively, if you were asked to define the natural numbers, you could do so axiomatically.  With this method, you begin by declaring an element is a natural number, and it really doesn't matter what this element is called, be it $0$ or $1$ or $\Delta$ - this is the idea I'm trying to convey.  Any set that satisfies the axioms we call the "natural numbers".  See here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Peano_axioms

Comment: Thanks!  Now I concluded that other sets __maybe__ considered as constant sets and we don't need to argue on it but set **N** is a variable set just like a variable 'x' which needs its values  to be defined before use. Right?

Comment: @Hritik exactly, you can never be sure what $\mathbb N$ means, however you can be sure it means EITHER positive integer or non-negative integer. However things like $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$ always mean the same thing, so we still have some sanity left.

Comment: Sure, that's a way of thinking about it @Hritik.  So long as the set satisfies the axioms, then it doesn't matter what the elements themselves are actually called.

Comment: So, there are two __types__ of N,
first - Which we call **whole numbers** and second **set Z+** . Am I right?

Comment: @Hritik yes, different people mean different things when they say "natural number", also if you want to write fancy maths, look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

The positive integers are $\mathbb Z^+=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, and it's always like that.

The natural numbers have different definitions depending on the book, sometimes the natural numbers is just the postivite integers $\mathbb N=\mathbb Z^+$, but other times the natural numbers are actually the non-negative numbers $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.

Some people also write $\mathbb N_0=\{0,1,2,\dots\},\mathbb Z^+=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and completely avoid $\mathbb N$ due to this ambiguity.

If you want to be completely unambigiuous, you should use the words positive integers and nonnegative integers for these sets.

Comment: What ? Natural numbers contain 0 ? 
I'm not talking about **some** books, laws of Maths must be universal.

Comment: @Hritik some people use different definitions for $\mathbb N$, what you call things doesn't change the laws of maths. Math is invariant under notation.

Comment: @Hritik, ...but definitions contain a certain degree of arbitrariness!

Comment: This just shows how bad my education system is. Alas, they never told us about the ambiguity in natural numbers. We were taught that natural number does not contain 0 whereas whole numbers contain 0. Happy that I learned something new today.

Comment: @Kaushik well the whole numbers typically also include the negative ones, so that's yet another one: $\mathbb Z = \{ \dots, - 2,-1,0,1, 2,\dots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question of whether or not the natural numbers should include zero, there are two arguments in favor of doing so that I find compelling:

1) By including zero, the natural numbers can then be used to indicate cardinalities for all finite sets.  If zero is not included, then the cardinality of the empty set is missing.

2) As John Conway pointed out, we already have a perfectly good way to describe the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$, namely the positive integers.  (JC was arguing why not to exclude zero from the natural numbers.)

Comment: We also have a perfectly good way to describe the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, namely the non-negative integers. Therefore I do not accept argument 2.

Comment: Monoids are often more useful than semigroups without additive identities.  Counting numbers (natural numbers without "zero") are a semigroup that can be used to define 1x=x and (N+1)x = Nx+x for any semigroup element x.  Natural numbers including zero can be used to extend that definition so that applying 0x to any monoid element x will yield its additive identity.  Being able to apply Nx to semigroups (which won't work if N can be zero) can be helpful, but so too can be the ability to use 0x to get the additive identity for x's monoid.

Answer (score 0):

People really are free in mathematics to define things any which way they please.  For me, the phrase "natural numbers" is most natural when identifying them and thus defining them by equating them with the counting numbers, that is numbers that are used to count things (countable nouns).  Once you equate the phrase "natural numbers" with "counting numbers" it's most 'natural' (pun intended) to jettison zero, unless of course you consider the absence of something part of your counting system.  But in that case it's unsatisfying to me because, when considering countable nouns, you can only get a sense of absence if you first have a sense of presence.  And when you consider what is present, you count those items using {1,2,3,...}, NOT {0,1,2,...}.  So I would urge all mathematicians, not just some of them, to get a life and define N as = {1,2,3,...}.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).