# Is the following statement true: "Any algebraic number can be raised to some integer power and become rational"?

Tags: polynomials, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I was recently reading a math book that was listing facts about $\pi$ and it said:

"$\pi$ is irrational, meaning it cannot be expressed as a fraction.

$\pi$ is also transcendental, meaning it is still irrational when raised to any power."

It's the second line that confuses me, as the way it is worded implies that any algebraic number can be raised to some power and become rational. But I haven't been able to find anything online mentioning this fact and whether or not is is true.

Can any algebraic number be raised to some power $n$ and become rational? (and is this a property algebraic numbers have, that transcendental numbers do not?)

Or is the book wrong?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that your book claimed that.  Can you supply the exact quote and reference?  If that claim really appears in your book, get another book.

Comment: A very introductory book for a non-mathematical audience might not be super careful with if-and-only-if connotations. It is certainly true that because $\pi$ is transcendental, we know that $\pi^n$ is irrational for all integers $n$; this just isn't a sufficient condition for being transcendental.

Comment: @lulu Its called "The Math Book" and its definitely a more basic-level math introduction, I'm mainly reading it for the math-history content

Comment: I suggest that you avoid popular mathematics as they are almost always full of insidious fundamental conceptual flaws. This includes **nearly all** youtube channels that I have come across, except for 3blue1brown. If I didn't mention a channel, assume by default that it is a bad source. There are so many **good** books aimed at the general audience (written by mathematically trained people) such as "Nets, Puzzles & Postmen", so there is no good reason to even look at bad sources. In short, for mathematics you would do well to stick to stuff written by mathematicians.

Comment: I think, if every algebraic number was simply of form $\sqrt[n]{\frac{p}{q}}$, then there would not be such an elaborate theory about which algebraic equations have [solutions in radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_in_radicals).

Comment: I have not read the book, hence not sure of the whole context ; I am also not supporting the Author ; But if you take "....π is also transcendental, meaning it is still irrational...." and take "meaning" == "IMPLYING" , then this is a true but weak statement, or a weak Theorem, not a Definition of transcendental Numbers ; "If t is transcendental, then t^(Positive Integer) is always irrational" ; The Author makes no claim made about Algebraic Numbers or Integers or Rational Numbers. If the Author claimed that this is the Definition, then that is wrong. [cont ==]

Comment: [== cont] Your own Query about "All Algebraic Numbers" is answered in the negative ; but that was not claimed by the Author ; that was "merely" your Doubt !

Comment: @Prem: I had that thought, but dismissed it because, no matter how you can choose to interpret it, the use of "meaning" in **both** quoted statements *one after another* makes it misleading to the point of being wrong. Good mathematical writers would never choose to write those sentences to convey the meaning in your proposed interpretation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The book is wrong. If, for instance, you raise $1+\sqrt2$ to some power $n$; you never get a rational number. Every number of the form $\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n$ can be written as $a+b\sqrt2$, with $a,b\in\Bbb N(=\{1,2,3,\ldots\})$, and it is therefore irrational.

Comment: ... of course, with $b\not=0$, which needs a little proof... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett I wrote that $b\in\Bbb N$ and, for me, $0\notin\Bbb N$.

Comment: Ah! Maybe for some fraction of the audience that merits clarification? Both the notation and the fact?

Comment: Is there any question in MSE about why the set of Natural Numbers $\mathbb N$ is not well-defined, as in, the inclusion of 0 is a matter of personal preference/based on the field of work? I would like to have some clarification.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I think that [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) is the natural place for that question.

Comment: @insipidintegrator eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220760/what-is-the-difference-between-natural-numbers-and-positive-integers/1220769#1220769 and related

Comment: If you have verified José's claim for all exponents up to some $n$, and if $(1+\sqrt 2)^n=a+b\sqrt 2$, for some two strictly positive integers $a$ and $b$, then to see it for exponent $n+1$ you just do: $$(a+b\sqrt 2)(1+\sqrt 2)=(a+2b)+(a+b)\sqrt 2$$ and it is clear that $a+2b$ and $a+b$ are again strictly positive integers.

Comment: @insipidintegrator: For me and almost all logicians, $0∈ℕ$. I have yet to see any convincing reason to consider $0∉ℕ$, and the 'example' over here doesn't convince me because we also have for every $x,r ∈ ℝ^+$ that $x > 1$ \implies $x^r > 1$; zero is special in many rings but doesn't warrant us excluding it from the ring. =)

Comment: @user21820 A colleague of mine loves to say that $0$ is the more natural of all integers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: At least, it's the most neutral. =P